# Google Map Place API with area border

Tags: google-maps

How to show the places with Area border? User will search in textbox and get a result like the image bellow. Google as a service provides that from map.google.com. But is there any API from where I can implement it in my website?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't provide that data via its APIs.  You can use the Embed API to display a map with that data on it (if that is all you need)

(An alternative to display it on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map, would be to use data from OpenStreetMaps: [proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3nudv6zy/2/), but that doesn't include the same data as Google Maps.)

[example of polygon on embed map](http://geocodezip.com/embed_example_KaraniganjBangladesh.html)

To change the location of the embedded map dynamically, change the src of the iframe:

[example of embed API map with changeable query](http://geocodezip.com/embed_example_KaraniganjBangladesh_dynamic.html)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```
<input id="searchString" value="Keraniganj, Bangladesh" onchange="changeLocation();" /><br>
<script>
function changeLocation() {
  var ifrm = document.getElementById('map');
  var srcUrl="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q="+document.getElementById("searchString").value+"&key=AIzaSyCxitB5jQcw7weQdg9MqBRfxr6mj81wT7I";
  ifrm.setAttribute('src',srcUrl);
}
</script>
<iframe id="map" 
  width="600" 
  height="450" 
  frameborder="0" 
  style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Keraniganj%2C%20Bangladesh&key=AIzaSyCxitB5jQcw7weQdg9MqBRfxr6mj81wT7I" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: This works, used this with react native WebView and it solved my problems.